# Play Framework Get Asset Server Side

Tags: playframework

This seems like it should be extremely easy, but I can't figure it out.  I need to get files from my /public folder on the server side of my application.  I can get them using javascript or html with no problems.  I'm using Java, play 2.2.1

I've tried messing around with this

```
Assets.at("/public", "images/someImage.png");
```

but I'm not sure how to turn that Action object into a File object.

Comment: You should just be able to open it as a `File`. i.e. `new File("public/images/someImage.jpg");`

Answer (score 2):

The 'public' folder probably won't exist on the file system in a deployed environment (using `$ activator stage`), as the assets are packed into a .jar file located at `target/universal/stage/lib/<PROJECT_NAME>-assets.jar`.

So getting a java.io.File instance to that location is AFAIK not possible.

However, this is what I figured out to read a file's bytes (And convert them to a String - that's what I needed):

SomeController.java

```java
private String getSomeFile() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = Play.application().resourceAsStream("public/some/file.txt");
        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 16];

        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        return new String(out.toByteArray(), "utf-8");
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { /* ignore */ }
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { /* ignore */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I used Play 2.3.7. I'm not sure if this will work on 2.2.1.

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score -1):

`Play.application().getFile` will load a file relative to the current application path.

So:

```
Play.application().getFile("public/images/someImage.png");
```

Comment: That works for getting the file when I'm running the server on localhost, but once it's packaged and deployed the file is then located at /projectName/projectName-version/lib/projectName.jar/public/images/someImage.png.  There has to be an easier way to get that file that doesn't involve a ClassLoader or something to get the file out of the jar.  Can't I somehow mimic the javascript way of doing it (@routes.Assets.at("images/someImage.png"))

Comment: `getFile` gets the file *relative* to the application path so why wouldn't it work in that situation?  In any case, Play will not serve arbitrary files off the filesystem unless they're in the classpath.